# Timed out waiting for transform from robot1/base_footprint to map ... tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, tf2, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am continuing my project to have several robots navigate using a shared map.

Here are my updated launch files after making changes to have separate namespaces for each robot.
Now my struggle is getting the map server to transform data which can feed the move_base.

file 1: navigation launch

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>
  <arg name="map_file" default="/home/in/GazeboHouseMap.yaml"/>
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3"  default="robot1"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3" default="robot2"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3"  default="robot3"/>
  <arg name="multi_robot_name" default=""/>

  <!-- Turtlebot3 -->
  <group ns = "$(arg first_tb3)">
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_remote.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="waffle_pi" /> 
    <arg name="multi_robot_name" value="robot1" />
  </include>
  </group>
  <group ns = "$(arg second_tb3)">
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_remote.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="waffle_pi" /> 
    <arg name="multi_robot_name" value="robot2" />
  </include>
  </group>
  <group ns = "$(arg third_tb3)">
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_remote.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="burger" /> 
    <arg name="multi_robot_name" value="robot3" />
  </include>
  </group>

  <!-- Map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)">
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map" />
  </node>

  <!-- AMCL -->
    <include file="$(find MoveOneOfThree)/launch/amcl_robot1.launch"/>
    <include file="$(find MoveOneOfThree)/launch/amcl_robot2.launch"/> 
    <include file="$(find MoveOneOfThree)/launch/amcl_robot3.launch"/> 

  <!-- MOVE_BASE -->
  <include file="$(find MoveOneOfThree)/launch/move_base_11.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="waffle_pi" />
    <arg name="move_forward_only" value="false"/>
  </include>
  <include file="$(find MoveOneOfThree)/launch/move_base_22.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="waffle_pi" />
    <arg name="move_forward_only" value="false"/>
  </include>
  <include file="$(find MoveOneOfThree)/launch/move_base_33.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="burger" />
    <arg name="move_forward_only" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <!-- rviz -->
  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find turtlebot3_navigation)/rviz/turtlebot3_navigation.rviz"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

file 2: AMCL

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="scan_topic"     default="/robot1/scan"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <group ns = "robot1">
  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">

    <param name="min_particles"             value="500"/>
    <param name="max_particles"             value="3000"/>
    <param name="kld_err"                   value="0.02"/>
    <param name="update_min_d"              value="0.20"/>
    <param name="update_min_a"              value="0.20"/>
    <param name="resample_interval"         value="1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance"       value="0.5"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a"            value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate"          value="50.0"/>

    <remap from="scan"                      to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    <param name="laser_max_range"           value="3.5"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams"           value="180"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit"               value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short"             value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max"               value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand"              value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit"           value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short"        value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type"          value="likelihood_field"/>

    <param name="odom_model_type"           value="diff"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id"             value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame_id"             value="base_footprint"/>

  </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

file 3: move_base

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="waffle_pi" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" default="robot1/cmd_vel" />
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="robot1/odom" />
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <group ns = "robot1">
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/dwa_local_planner_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x" value="0.0" if="$(arg move_forward_only)" />
  </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397426/timed-out-waiting-for-transform-from-robot1/base_footprint-to-map-...-tf-error:-cantransform:-target_frame-map-does-not-exist/) by [JustinPMaio](https://answers.ros.org/users/98773/justinpmaio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What a month it has been but I FINALLY got it! The key piece I was missing was that even though the robots all share the same map, they each still need their own map server. I updated the  section as follows:

```
  <!-- Map server -->
<group ns = "$(arg first_tb3)">
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)">
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map" />
  </node>
  </group>
<group ns = "$(arg second_tb3)">
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)">
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map" />
  </node>
  </group>
<group ns = "$(arg third_tb3)">
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)">
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map" />
  </node>
  </group>
```

I also had to give each robot their own set of params for the move_base file. All the params that look like this  have to be updated so that they use the correct frame with namespace preceding base_link, etc.

---

Originally posted by [JustinPMaio](https://answers.ros.org/users/98773/justinpmaio/) with karma: 21 on 2022-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1